# Drawing some simple circular, rectangular and triangular shapes

Tags: diagrams, plot

I want to draw the following shapes. Would you please help me? Thanks a lot.

[image: Different norms]

@peter It is so useful, thanks a lot for your attention, but actually I want to draw this figure. Sorry for inconvenience. I am a little amateur.

Comment: Have a look at [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/). Can you show us with a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), what you have tried until now?

Comment: In addition: Because Tikz is a very large LaTeX package, I would recommend to read an introduction/tutorial, first. It helps to get a first impression how to use it. For example, [Graphics with TikZ](https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/mertz/mertz.pdf) and [A very minimal introduction to TikZ](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf) look moderate. After this, I would take a look into the [official documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). The graphics you want to create are perfect in the beginning! Good luck!

Comment: You can find a similar question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191518/beginner-drawing-using-tikz/191520#191520

Comment: You also can take a look at `pstricks` and `pst-plot`, which are very well documented. They can be compiled with `pdflatex`if you load your document class with option `pdf`, provided odflatex is launched with the `--shell-escape` switch (TeX Live, MacTeX) or `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX).

Comment: What is the general equation for the figures, i.e., the equation involving p?

Answer (score 7):

<sub>This is another boring after noon with some free time. To explain code, it will be terribly boring though!</sub>

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [<->] (-4,0)--(4,0);
\draw [<->] (0,-4)--(0,4);
\draw[blue] (-3,0) -- (0,3) -- (3,0) -- (0,-3) -- (-3,0);
\node at (0,-4.5) {$p=1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [<->] (-4,0)--(4,0);
\draw [<->] (0,-4)--(0,4);
\draw[blue] (0,0) circle[x radius=3cm,y radius=2.6cm];
\node at (0,-4.5) {$p=2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [<->] (-4,0)--(4,0);
\draw [<->] (0,-4)--(0,4);
\draw[blue] (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
\node at (0,-4.5) {$p=\infty$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [<->] (-4,0)--(4,0);
\draw [<->] (0,-4)--(0,4);
\draw[blue] (-3,0) 
            to[bend right] (0,3) 
            to[bend right] (3,0) 
            to[bend right] (0,-3) 
            to[bend right] (-3,0);
\node at (0,-4.5) {$p=\frac{1}{2}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @peter It is so useful, thanks a lot for your attention, but actually I want to draw this figure, sorry for inconvenience I am a little amateur.

Answer (score 5):

Unit balls so why not `pgfplots`?

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,axis equal,enlargelimits,xmax=1,ymax=1,xmin=-1,ymin=-1]
%p=0.5
\begin{scope}[very thick,dotted,orange,domain=0:pi,samples=50]
\addplot[] ({(cos(deg(x)))^(4},{ (sin(deg(x))^(4});
\addplot[] ({(cos(deg(x)))^(4},{ -(sin(deg(x))^(4});
\addplot[] ({-(cos(deg(x)))^(4},{ (sin(deg(x))^(4});
\addplot[] ({-(cos(deg(x)))^(4},{-(sin(deg(x))^(4});
\end{scope}
%p=1
\addplot[blue,domain=0:pi] ({(cos(deg(x)))^2},{(sin(deg(x))^2});
\addplot[blue,domain=0:pi] ({(cos(deg(x)))^2},{-(sin(deg(x))^2});
\addplot[blue,domain=0:pi] ({-(cos(deg(x)))^2},{(sin(deg(x))^2});
\addplot[blue,domain=0:pi] ({-(cos(deg(x)))^2},{-(sin(deg(x))^2});
%p=2
\addplot[red,domain=-pi:0] ({(cos(deg(x)))},{(sin(deg(x))});
\addplot[red,domain=0:pi] ({(cos(deg(x)))},{(sin(deg(x))});
%p=inf
\draw[thick,dashdotted,gray] (axis cs:-1,-1) rectangle (axis cs:1,1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This one is just a modification of [percusse's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196152/29394), to use loops instead of having big chunks of code:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

% Unit circle plot style
\pgfplotsset{unit circle/.style={width=4cm,height=4cm,axis lines=middle,xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,axis equal,enlargelimits,xmax=1,ymax=1,xmin=-1,ymin=-1,domain=0:pi/2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (prev); % Store previous plot position
    \foreach \p / \t in {4/\frac{1}{2}, 2/1, 1/2, 0.0001/\infty} { % Loop through the plots to draw
        % \p is the exponent in the function to plot
        % \t is the p parameter to print
        \begin{axis}[at={(prev)},unit circle,anchor=west]
            \foreach \ss in {1,-1} {
            \foreach \cs in {1,-1} {
                \addplot[] ({\cs*(cos(deg(x)))^\p},{\ss*(sin(deg(x))^\p});
            }
            }
        \end{axis}
        \node[below=0.5cm, anchor=base] at (current axis.south) {$p=\t$}; % Print p
        \coordinate[right=0.5cm] (prev) at (current axis.east) ; % Set position for next plot
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: As noted by percusse, this solution is a bit cheating to draw the unit circle for the [maximum norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_norm), approximating it with the 20000-norm. I believe it looks good enough, though. Also, every unit circle is drawn with 4 plots, even when only one could do.

If you want other p-norm to be drawn, just add them to the list. The exponent `\p` should be a numerical value equal (or close) to 2/p, and `\t` a printable representation of p.

[image: rendering]

Comment: still, very nice :)

Comment: @TonioELGringo your help is so worthy, would you please check edited question and answer it?