# TikZ: Draw different shapes of lp-Norm

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes

I am trying to reproduce the picture below using Ti*k*Z.

[image]

A similar question was already asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196135/drawing-some-simple-circular-rectangular-and-triangular-shapes/), but I wasn't able to apply the answers to my problem since I need the exact same picture not only the shapes. I tried to modify the given answers but that didn't lead to anything useful because I don't really understand `pgfplots` and I'm relatively new to Ti*k*Z ...

That is what I have done so far.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \foreach \x in {0,4.5,9,13.5}{
      \draw [->] (-1.2-\x,0)--(2.5-\x,0);
      \draw [->] (0-\x,-1.2)--(0-\x,1.7);
      \draw[shorten <=-1cm, shorten >=-3mm] (0-\x,1)--(2-\x,0) node [midway, above] {$A$};
   }

   \draw[blue] (-10,0)--(-9,1)--(-8,0)--(-9,-1)--cycle;
   \draw [blue](-4.5,0) circle (0.88cm);

   \foreach \x in {0.66}{
      \draw[blue] (-\x,-\x)--(-\x,\x)--(\x,\x)--(\x,-\x)--cycle;
   }

   \draw[blue,scale=1,domain=0:90,samples=100,smooth,variable=\t]
      plot({-1*cos(\t)^(3)-13.5},{1*sin(\t)^(3)});
   \draw[blue,scale=1,domain=0:90,samples=100,smooth,variable=\t]
      plot({-1*cos(\t)^(3)-13.5},{-1*sin(\t)^(3)});
   \draw[blue,scale=1,domain=0:90,samples=100,smooth,variable=\t]
      plot({1*cos(\t)^(3)-13.5},{-1*sin(\t)^(3)});
   \draw[blue,scale=1,domain=0:90,samples=100,smooth,variable=\t]
      plot({1*cos(\t)^(3)-13.5},{1*sin(\t)^(3)});                 

\end{tikzpicture}
```

The picture below shows the result. The code is horrific but it is the best I can come up with for now ...

[image: p-Norm for p=2/3,1,2,infty]

Comment: could you please post what have you done so far?

Comment: @naphaneal

yes, but how do i display code in the comment environment? or should i use the "Answer Your Question" button?

Comment: click on `edit` in your question, paste your code, mark it, then click on the `{}` symbol. your code will be displayed on a grey background.

Comment: Are the shapes supposed to be cosmetic? As in, no actual mathematical precision?

Comment: Please always post compilable code, rather than just a fragment as it makes it much easier to reproduce what you are seeing.

Comment: Hmm. If these are the only pictures you need to know how to do them in TikZ,  asking others how to create them is probably OK. However, if you need more of them, perhaps it's better if you learn TikZ.

Comment: @cfr Sorry, I will regard that in my future questions.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Yes, you're right, but I only needed that one picture. If I need TikZ frequently in the future then of course I will learn TikZ instead of letting others do my work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly something like this? It may not be maximally efficient as I started from the code in the question and something which plots each one might provide greater elegance.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth]
   \foreach \i in {0,...,3}{
     \begin{scope}[xshift=\i*4.5cm]
      \draw [<->] (-1.2,0)--(2.5,0);
      \draw [<->] (0,-1.2)--(0,1.7);
      \draw[shorten <=-1cm, shorten >=-3mm] (0,1)--(2,0) node [midway, above] {$A$};
    \end{scope}
   }
   \begin{scope}[draw=blue, densely dashed]
     \draw [] (-1,0)--(0,1)--(1,0)--(0,-1)--cycle;
     \draw [](4.5,0) circle (0.88cm);
     \draw [xshift=9cm] (-.66,-.66) rectangle (.66,.66);
     \begin{scope}[xshift=13.5cm]
       \draw [domain=0:90,samples=100,smooth,variable=\t] plot({-1*cos(\t)^(3)},{1*sin(\t)^(3)});
       \draw [domain=0:90,samples=100,smooth,variable=\t] plot({-1*cos(\t)^(3)},{-1*sin(\t)^(3)});
       \draw [domain=0:90,samples=100,smooth,variable=\t] plot({1*cos(\t)^(3)},{-1*sin(\t)^(3)});
       \draw [domain=0:90,samples=100,smooth,variable=\t] plot({1*cos(\t)^(3)},{1*sin(\t)^(3)});
     \end{scope}
     \foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {(0,1),(.39,.79),(.66,.66),(0,1)} \scoped [xshift=\j*4.5cm] { \draw [{Circle[width=3pt, length=3pt, fill=black, black]}-{Circle[width=3pt, length=3pt, fill=black, black]}, shorten <=-1.5pt, shorten >=-1.5pt] (0,0) node [below left] {$x$} -- \i node [above right] {$\hat x$} ; };
   \end{scope}
   \foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {1,2,\infty,\frac{1}{2}} \scoped [xshift=\j*4.5cm] { \node [anchor=mid west] at (0,-1.5) {$p=\i$}; };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: variations on a unitary theme]